# Reference to table into appendix

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I am a new user of latex and I want write in my text some reference to several table in appendix

[image]

If from a chapter write `\ref{tab:1d_1_sta}` I have only `A.1` and not `A.1.1`

How can solve this problems???

This is the appendix code

```
\begin{appendix}

                \chapter{Complete results of Simulation: Multiplex PI}\label{appA}
                    \section{Set one - Mono-dimensional case}
                    Stability Region
                    \begin{table}[H]
                        \label{tab:1d_1_sta}
                        \input{../MATLAB/SIMULATION_IMAGE/SIMULATION_9_NODES/PI_9_1D_1_VER1/unstability_region}
                        \caption{Percentage of the area of the unstability region}
                    \end{table}
```

Comment: you need to make `\label{tab:1d_1_sta}` after caption

Comment: Please do not post just fragments of code

Comment: @touhami Thanks a lot! If you reply as answer I accept it (sei un grande in italiano) ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\label{tab:1d_1_sta}` need to be used after `\caption{...}` otherwise it refers to the section number.

Comment: @LucaAngelino you're welcome.